# How do I retrieve a public/private key from a file using BouncyCastle?

Tags: java, cryptography, key, bouncycastle, decoding

I'm having a hard time understanding how to use a private and public key file given to me.

I have 2 files, `public.pem` and `private.pem`. I'm trying to use BouncyCastle to get the public and private keys. I wrote this class to try and extract the keys:

```
public class KeyReaders {

    public static class PublicKeyReader {

        public static byte[] get(String filename)
                throws Exception {

            FileReader f = new FileReader(filename);

            PEMParser pp = new PEMParser(f);
            SubjectPublicKeyInfo  o = (SubjectPublicKeyInfo )pp.readObject();

            return o.parsePublicKey().getEncoded();
        }
    }

    public static class PrivateKeyReader {

        public static byte[] get(String filename)
                throws Exception {

            FileReader f = new FileReader(filename);

            PEMParser pp = new PEMParser(f);
            PEMKeyPair o = (PEMKeyPair)pp.readObject();


            return  o.getPrivateKeyInfo().getEncoded();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to use these keys to decode a file. I have a file, `test.txt`, which I can't use the private key to decode. I'm not 100% sure this is even the appropriate way to read in a .PEM file.

So, how do I use BouncyCastle to decode a text file, given the private key file?

Comment: Immediately re-encoding them to a `byte[]` seems like a mistake. Any crypto API is likely to require the `PublicKey` or `PrivateKey` you've decoded.

Comment: I'm having troubles figuring out how to get the base PublicKey and PrivateKey, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are trying to produce a regular JCA key pair. Have you tried using the JcaPEMKeyConverter class? It is in the org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce package.